# Solving Kepler's second law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, applications, mathematical-astronomy

Kepler's second law, about equal areas in equal times, is a differential equation: it gives velocity as a function of location.

Where are the best expository accounts of the process of solving this equation, giving position as a function of time?

Comment: Are you looking more for a historical account of the problem and the experimental evidence which supported the law? Or are you looking instead for purely mathematical modern treatment of the problem? I think Carroll's astrophysics text is a good reference in either case, from what I recall.

Comment: Kepler's second law is (equivalent to) a statement about angular momentum being conserved. As such, it is valid for _any_ central force, of which the inverse-square law is but one example. To proceed further, we need Kepler's _first_ law as well (orbits are ellipses with sun at a focus). See this [link](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m231f07/m231f07NewtonKeplerConverse.pdf) for a nice account.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : I had in mind primarily the math, but the history would also be of interest.

Comment: [These notes](http://goo.gl/4MM4l1) aren't so bad.

Comment: To state the issue a little differently: Kepler's second law (the constancy of areal velocity) is a differential equation which gives the _angular_ velocity $\dot{\theta(t)}$ as a function of _radial_ position $r(t)$. Hence it isn't reasonable to expect that we can deduce either coordinate $r(t)$ or $\theta(t)$ as functions of time _unless_ we have one additional relationship (e.g. $\ddot{r}\propto -r^{-2}$ (gravitational force law), $r=r(\theta)$ is an ellipse (Kepler's first law).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's a consequence of the rotation invariance of the system. So, for any given $\hat{z}$ axis, perpendicular to the orbit plane, the $z$ angular momentum component is a constant of motion:

$$
M_z=ymv_x - xmv_y =2m\left(\,{1 \over 2}\,r^2 \dot{\theta}\,\right)
=2m\,{{\rm d}\text{Area} \over {\rm d}t}
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right. However, the OP didn't ask for a solution. He just said

$$\sf\mbox{Where are the best expository accounts of the process of solving this equation,... ?}"
$$.